# Disallowing page breaks mid section when printing

Tags: css

I have the following structure and I'm trying to stop page breaks in the middle of `<section class="section"></section>` when printing:

HTML:

```
<div class="tailoredmenu">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div role="main">
      <article class="article">
        <section class="section">...</section>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I'm trying which bizarrely only works sometimes:

CSS:

```
.tailoredmenu > .wrap > .article > .section {
    page-break-before: auto;
    page-break-after: auto;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Also tried:

```
.tailoredmenu > .wrap > .article > section {
    page-break-before: auto;
    page-break-after: auto;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: I may be incorrect but doesn't the `>` imply a direct descendent where your `.article` is a descendent of the `.main` rather than the `.wrap` class? So `.tailoredmenu > .wrap > .main > .article > .section` would be more likely to work?

Comment: main is not a class, it's a role, and as such don't think it figures in the hierachy

Comment: sorry I mis-read that